# Open Image from IsolatedStoreage?

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, exception

I want to open an Image from the IsolatedStorage?

The image was downloaded before and correctly written (I checked that with the Isolated Storage Explorer).

When I try to open the Image with BitmapImage(uriInIsolatedStorage) and set that as source for a Silverlight Image Control it crashs when I listen to the image failed event.

The exception said "AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR"

Does anyone has an idea?

```
Uri imageSource = new Uri("/cover.jpg",  UriKind.Relative);
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(imageSource);
bi.ImageFailed += new EventHandler<ExceptionRoutedEventArgs>(MainPage_ImageFailed);
bi.ImageOpened +=new EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs>(bi_ImageOpened);
imageCtrl.Source = bi;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot load an image directly from isolated storage via URI. You have to open the file and do some more steps as described [here](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/73544.aspx) or (a bit easier) [here](http://www.j2i.net/blogEngine/post/2011/09/03/Displaying-an-Image-from-Isolated-Storage.aspx).

It boils down to:

- creating an `IsolatedStorageFileStream` for your image
- creating a `BitmapImage` from file data
- setting `BitmapImage` as `Image` source

There is also an `isostore:` URI scheme but it doesn't work.